# The largest domain where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}$ is holomorphic

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I want to find the largest domain where $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nz^n}{1-z^n}$ is holomorphic. I know $f(z)$ is holomorphic in the unitary disk, $\mathbb{D}$, and I believe that it is the largest domain.

I am trying to prove it by contradiction. Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ open, then $\mathbb{D}\subset U$. Take $z\in U\backslash \mathbb{D}$, then $|z|\geq 1$. So I am trying to prove that the series diverges in that case, but I have been able only to prove that when $|z|>1$ then the series doesn't converge absolutely.

So my questions is:
How can I prove it doesn't converge when $|z|\geq 1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let |z|=1. Thus $z=e^{i\theta}$. The set of all such $z$ (for $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$) forms a multiplicative group, using the multiplication of $\mathbb{C}.$

If $z$ has finite order in the group, then infinitely often the general term $f_n(z)$ is undefined. So for such $z$ there is no convergence.

Otherwise $z$ has infinite order in the circle group, so the general term $f_n(z)$ is always defined. We have: $$|f_n(z)|\,=\,\frac{n\,|z|^n}{|1-z^n|}\,\geq\,\frac{n\,|z|^n}{1+|z|^n}\,=\,\frac{n}{1+1},$$

so there is no convergence of the series for any $z$ on the unit circumference. If $|z|>1$, we estimate:

$$|f_n(z)|\,=\,\frac{n\,|z|^n}{|1-z^n|}\,\geq\,\frac{n\,|z|^n}{1+|z|^n}\,>\,\frac{n|z|^n}{2|z|^n}\,=\,\frac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: As I understand you proved that the series doesn't converge absolutely. However, how proving that the series doesn't converge absolutely implies that the series doesn't converge? (or is not holomorphic?) @311411

Comment: The reasoning goes this way. Assume, for a contradiction, that there exists $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|\zeta|\geq1$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\zeta^n}{1-\zeta^n}$ converges to $\omega.$ If so, the sequence $\frac{n\zeta^n}{1-\zeta^n}\,\to\,0,$ as $n\to\infty.$ So for all $n$ big enough, $|\frac{n\zeta^n}{1-\zeta^n}|\,<\,0.001.$ But the inequalities I have derived tell a very different story. Your series does not provide a complex-valued function for $\{|z|\geq 1\}$.